# Can't reach table's row while simulating api call in react testing library with jest

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I'm trying in my test to make mocked api call and check if my table has 3 rows of data. That's part of the code I want to test:

```
export const getContactRequests = async (source: string) => {
  const response = await axios({
    method: "get",
    url: source,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("currentToken")}`,
    },
    withCredentials: true,
  });

  return response.data.data;
};

export default function ContactRequestsTable() {
 const [contactRequests, setContactRequests] = useState<ContactRequest[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
    getContactRequests(`${variables.getApi}user/contact-requests`).then(
      (data) => setContactRequests(data)
    );
  }, []);

return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>{t("profile:request-email")}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{t("profile:request-phone")}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{t("profile:request-created")}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{t("profile:request-updated")}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{t("profile:request-actions")}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {contactRequests.map((request) => (
            <TableRow
              key={request.id}
              sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
            >
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {request.customer_email}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{request.customer_phone}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">
                {dayjs(request.created_at).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">
                {dayjs(request.updated_at).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">
                <TooltipComponent
                  WrappedComponent={
                    <HiOutlineMagnifyingGlassCircle
                      onClick={() => openDialog(DialogFunction.Show)}
                    />
                  }
                  message={t("profile:show-message")}
                />
                <TooltipComponent
                  WrappedComponent={
                    <HiXCircle
                      onClick={() => openDialog(DialogFunction.Delete)}
                    />
                  }
                  message={t("profile:edit")}
                />
                <Dialog
                  open={open}
                  onClose={handleClose}
                  className="contact-request-dialog"
                  BackdropProps={{
                    style: { backgroundColor: "transparent" },
                  }}
                >
                  {showDialog(request)}
                </Dialog>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Then we have data I want to use in test:

```
export const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    offer_id: "7af46784-7d47-4478-95f1-9d281cf91338",
    message: "Corporis eum assumenda eos maxime eveniet et officia non.",
    customer_email: "Kaley_Heaney9@example.com",
    customer_phone: "926-494-3521",
    created_at: "2023-11-07T14:05:36.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2023-11-07T14:05:36.000000Z",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    offer_id: "7af46784-7d47-4478-95f1-9d281cf91338",
    message: "Omnis qui eligendi autem blanditiis unde sint id voluptate.",
    customer_email: "Judy95@example.net",
    customer_phone: "458-775-2750",
    created_at: "2023-11-07T14:06:58.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2023-11-07T14:06:58.000000Z",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    offer_id: "7af46784-7d47-4478-95f1-9d281cf91338",
    message: "Officiis omnis omnis suscipit eaque incidunt delectus.",
    customer_email: "Kaley_Heaney9@example.com",
    customer_phone: "717-203-5785",
    created_at: "2023-11-07T14:07:33.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2023-11-07T14:07:33.000000Z",
  },
];
```

And a test file:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import ContactRequestsTable from "../ContactRequestsTable";
import { data } from "./Contact-request.mock";
import axios from "axios";

describe("ContactRequests component", () => {
  it("shows contact requests coming from servers", async () => {
    jest.spyOn(axios, "get").mockResolvedValue({
      data: data,
    });
    render(<ContactRequestsTable />);

    // Wait for the component to fetch and render the data
    const dataElement1 = await screen.findByText(
      "Corporis eum assumenda eos maxime eveniet et officia non."
    );
    const dataElement2 = await screen.findByText(
      "Omnis qui eligendi autem blanditiis unde sint id voluptate."
    );
    const dataElement3 = await screen.findByText(
      "Officiis omnis omnis suscipit eaque incidunt delectus."
    );

    // Assert that the component renders the mocked data
    expect(dataElement1).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(dataElement2).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(dataElement3).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
});
```

Tried many approaches and still don't know why my <tbody> is empty. Do you have any ideas?

I invoked the exported function in testing file to try to solve the problem and use msw. Msw wasn't working for me and invoking function gave me setTimeout error.